# Alinhamento de checkbox

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Fala pessoal, beleza?

Sou iniciante, acabou surgindo uma dificuldade de alinhar meu checkbox, se alguém puder dar uma dica de como devo proceder, segue o trecho do meu HTML:

```
<li>
    <label class="bloco">Deseja receber novidades por email:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="novidade" checked /> Sim
    <input type="radio" name="novidade" /> Não
</li>
<li>
    <label class="bloco">Como nos encontrou?</label>
    Indicação <input type="checkbox" name="divulg" /> <br>
    Redes Sociais <input type="checkbox" name="divulg" /> <br>
    E-mail <input type="checkbox" name="divulg" /> 
</li>
```

E CSS:

```
form#contato ul li label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80px;
    font: 18px Lucida; }

form#contato ul li label.bloco {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: center;
    height: 30px; }

label.bloco {
    font-weight: italic;
    font-family: lucida;
    font-size: 18px; }
```

Comment: Vi que se cadastrou hoje na comunidade, talvez seja interessante fazer o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) caso já não tenha feito. Não poste seus códigos como imagem, o sistema possui suporte nativo para os mesmos, basta copiá-lo na pergunta, selecioná-lo e clicar no botão `{ }` para formatá-lo corretamente (ou pressionar o atalho `CTRL + K`).

Comment: para fazer o alinhamento de chebox você pode está utilizando o "vertical-align" do CSS, mas isso se torna mais fácil se você trabalhar com classes diferentes, dos demais elementos do formulário, exemplo:
[![Alinhamento de checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgrJB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgrJB.png)

Comment: Teria como postar o código fonte ao invés das imagens? Aproveitando. tente criar um [mcve] para nos ajudar a identificar o seu problema.
Você sempre pode fazer o[tour] e entender melhor o funcionamento geral do site. xD

Comment: Obrigado pelo toque, desculpe a falha!!

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer um checkbox com um frase, coloque um label em volta de cada checkbox, dessa forma ao clicar na frase ele também clica no input:

```
<label>
Indicação <input type="checkbox" name="divulg" />
</label>
```

eu retirei o width que você havia colocado, caso ainda esteja desalinhado, tente aumentar o width e pode alinhar o input da seguinte forma:

```
label{
    display:inline-block;
    font:18px Lucida;
    float:left;
}
label input{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Bacana, deu certo!

Consegui solucionar meu problema!

Comment: olá eu  reparei  no seu código que faltou vocÊ colocar o value no seu checkbox

Comment: @Danilorodrigues Sim, no caso eu fiz igual ao exemplo dele, também não é necessário colocar value no checkbox, por padrão o value dele já é "on"